# Removing an href value, if it exists using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What would the best way to remove an href that has a specific value using jquery if it is found in the DOM.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a').each(function () {
            var hrefValue = $(this).attr("href")
            if (hrefValue == '/remove/thehrefvalue?when=now') {
               //remove only a href containing this specific value
            }

        });
    });
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of iterating through *every* `a`, you can iterate through only `a`s which have that particular `href` attribute by altering the selector string:

```
$('a[href="/remove/thehrefvalue?when=now"]').remove();
```

```js
$('a[href="/remove/thehrefvalue?when=now"]').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/remove/thehrefvalue?when=now">now</a>
<a href="/remove/thehrefvalue?when=now">now</a>
<a href="/remove/thehrefvalue?when=notnow">notnow</a>
<a href="/remove/thehrefvalue?when=now">now</a>
```

(Not entirely sure what you're looking for. If you wanted to remove the `<a>`s, use the code above - if you wanted to remove the attributes but leave the `<a>`s alone, use `removeAttr('href')` instead of `.remove()`)

Comment: `$('a[href="/remove/thehrefvalue?when=now"]').removeAttr('href')`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('a').each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("href") == '/remove/thehrefvalue?when=now') {
               $(this).removeAttr("href");
            }

        });
    });
```